# boost::lexical_cast and double -- strange behavior

Tags: c++, boost

Why does the following code gives me the different results when I write `"2.01"` and `"2.02"`?

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  const std::string str = "2.02";

  try
  {
    const double b = boost::lexical_cast<double>(str) * 100.0;
    std::cout << "double: " << b << '\n';
    const int a = boost::lexical_cast<int>(b);
    std::cout << "int: " << a << '\n';
  }
  catch (const std::exception& ex)
  {
    std::cerr << ex.what() << '\n';
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
double: 202
int: 202
```

But if I change `"2.02"` to the `"2.01"` it gives me the following output:

```
double: 201
bad lexical cast: source type value could not be interpreted as target
```

Why?

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 (msvc-12.0) and boost 1.57.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It's floating point inaccuracy.

There's no *exact* representation of 2.01 in binary floating point so, multiplying by 100 doesn't result in an integer number.

You can make it visible: **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/beda0b8a15000bb7)</kbd>**

```
std::cout << "double: " << std::setprecision(18) << std::fixed << b << '\n';
```

Prints

```
double: 200.999999999999971578
```

Conversion to int fails for this reason.

Comment: The solution would be to cast it to double first, and then to it, right?

Comment: Can `lexical_cast` be used for numeric conversions like in OP's code? isn't it designed only for conversions to/from a string-like type?

Comment: @g.tsh No. The solution would be to use decimal representation or integral arithmetics. And don't forget about the fact that decimal representations still have precision limits (like 10/3 = 3.333333...)

Comment: @PiotrS. That's a funny question (it's answered by the code running). Anyhoops [Returns the result of streaming arg into a standard library string-based stream and then out as a Target object](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/synopsis.html#boost_lexical_cast.synopsis.lexical_cast)